# activeadmin formtastic f.template.image_tag(...) showing an extra hash at form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-5

At active admin, I have this following code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Item do

  permit_params :name, :description, :avatar

  form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :name
      f.input :description

      f.input :avatar, :as => :file  , :hint => f.template.image_tag(f.object.avatar.url(:medium))
    end
    f.actions
  end

end
```

It shows a class hash at the form,[image: unwanted hash demo]

HTML:

```
<fieldset class="inputs"><ol><li class="string input optional stringish" id="item_name_input"><label for="item_name" class="label">Name</label><input id="item_name" type="text" name="item[name]">

</li><li class="text input optional" id="item_description_input"><label for="item_description" class="label">Description</label><textarea rows="20" id="item_description" name="item[description]"></textarea>

</li>#&lt;#&lt;Class:0x007fb884ba0970&gt;:0x007fb886102b38&gt;<li class="file input optional" id="item_avatar_input"><label for="item_avatar" class="label">Avatar</label><input id="item_avatar" type="file" name="item[avatar]">

<p class="inline-hints"><img src="/images/medium/missing.png" alt="Missing"></p></li></ol></fieldset>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: please post about 10 lines before and 10 after around this code

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Thats everything I have in that file!

Comment: check what  inspect element shows at that place

Comment: @AndreyDeineko added html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to `hint: image_tag(f.object.avatar.url(:medium)).html_safe`, `f.template` is excess here.

Comment: Thanks but this failed `:hint => image_tag(f.object.avatar.url(:medium)).html_safe` but 'hint: image_tag(f.object.avatar.url(:medium)).html_safe' worked, why is that?

Comment: @sadaf2605 I didn't get it, what is worked and what is not?